# fn:min function not working

Tags: xquery, flwor

Okay so I have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dvdCollection xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://teste1.org"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://teste1.org dvds.xsd">
<dvd>
<id>1</id>
<title>Pulp Fiction</title>
<release-year>1994</release-year>
<director>Quentin Tarantino</director>
<actors>
< actor type="star" gender="male">John Travolta</actor>
<actor type="star" gender="female">Uma Thurman</actor>
<actor type="co-star" gender="male">Samuel L. Jackson</actor>
</actors>
<genres><genre>Crime</genre><genre>Drama</genre></genres>
</dvd>
<dvd>
<id>2</id>
<title>Green mile</title>
<release-year>1993</release-year>
<director>Quentin Tarantino</director>
<actors>
<actor type="star" gender="male">Tom hanks</actor>
</actors>
<genres><genre>Crime</genre></genres>
</dvd>
<dvd>
<id>3</id>
<title>Titanic</title>
<release-year>1999</release-year>
<director>Quentin Tarantino</director>
<actors>
<actor type="star" gender="male">Tom hanks</actor>
</actors>
<genres><genre>Crime</genre></genres>
</dvd>
</dvdCollection>
```

I'm trying to fetch the minimum release-year with Crime genre. This is my query
but for some reason its returning all the release years like this:

1994
1993
1999

I'm puting a sequence like this inside fn:min

```
 <release-year xmlns="http://teste1.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">1994</release-year>
 <release-year xmlns="http://teste1.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">1993</release-year>
 <release-year xmlns="http://teste1.org" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">1999</release-year>
```

I was given the impression fn:min would flatten my sequence, what am I'm doing wrong, can someone explain how this function works ?

query:

```
    declare default element namespace "http://teste1.org";
    let $dvds := fn:doc("dvdcollection.xml")//dvd
    for $dvd in $dvds//genre[.="Crime"]
    let $min := fn:min($dvd/../../release-year)
    return $min
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody who has a similar mistake:
Okay so fn:min does what I tought it would, the problem was that I was applying fn:min to each element because of the for instruction. This is not what I wanted, I wanted to group a sequence of release-years, so it was pretty simple what I needed to to do!

```
declare default element namespace "http://teste1.org";
let $dvds := fn:doc("dvdcollection.xml")//dvd
**let** $dvd := $dvds//genre[.="Crime"]
let $min := fn:min($dvd/../../release-year)
return $min
```

Just replace that "for" for a "let" and the mistake is cleared.